# Code Analysis in visual studio 2013

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, code-analysis

I am developing a project in Vb.Net in VS2012. I checked that in the VS there is a tool which can analyze the code used in the project. But it can only run the code analysis tool for whole solution/project. Now if I want to run code analysis tool for specific screen or form. Can it be possible?

Can any one guide me to find out the way to run code analysis tool for particular form or screen.

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know this isn't possible with VS tools. You could do this with tools like Resharper though...

Comment: What aspects of your code are you analysing?

Comment: @timothyclifford I am looking code analysis for code quality and performance improvement perspective.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio do you have? Are you also using ReSharper?

Comment: And what about StyleCop and FxCop?